# Can you use the default event content with a custom button in FullCalendar React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I'm using fullcalendar/react to build a custom calendar with events on them. On each of the events, I want to add a material UI icon button in the bottom right corner of the event, but when I use the `eventContent` props on the Calendar, it completely replaces the default event component.

I really like the default event component, and I don't want to try to recreate it. I just want to render my custom button over it. Does anyone know of a way that I can do that, or achieve something like it?

To be clear, I'm *not* talking about the custom buttons for the header. I want to be able to render a button on the events *inside* the calendar.

Right now I render a custom event and pass that into the `eventContent` hook, which behaves exactly as I would expect -- it completely replaces the default event component provided by fullcalendar. I would just like a way to keep the default event component and add my custom button to it.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks - eventDidMount gives you access to the html element so you can make modifications to the inner content

Comment: Oh okay, I saw that hook but didn't realize that it actually returned the element! I'll give that a shot, thank you.